# Unable to scrape data from https://www.gbgb.org.uk/meeting/?meetingId=355352&raceId=576255

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi for some reason I cannot seem to scrape any results data from https://www.gbgb.org.uk/ using BS, I can print the results page page I want using prettify but as soon as I ask for a "find_all" for example I get a 0 return, can anyone see if I'm doing anything wrong as the same code works fine on other sites, below is a quick example of what I mean, many thanks

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from requests import get
url = 'https://www.gbgb.org.uk/meeting/?meetingId=355490&raceId=577749'
response = get(url)
#print(response.text[:500])

headers = {}
headers['User-Agent'] ="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17"
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = headers)


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)
#print(html_soup.prettify())

info_container = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'MeetingRaceTrap')
print(type(info_container))
print(len(info_container))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to `NetWork` Tab.You will get following API which returns result as json format.

```
https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/355490?meeting=355490
```

You don't need BeautifulSoup here.

```
import requests
import json
headers = {'User-Agent':
       'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/355490?meeting=355490'
response =requests.get(url,headers=headers)
data=json.loads(response.text)
print(data)
```

Now lets say you want get `races`
Just print

```
print(data[0]['races'])
```

Or you want to get prizes for races.

```
for price in data[0]['races']:
    print(price['racePrizes'])
```

Your output will be

```
1st £95 | Others £40 | Race Total £95
1st £95 | Others £40 | Race Total £295
1st £105 | Others £40 | Race Total £305
1st £100 | Others £40 | Race Total £300
1st £120 | Others £40 | Race Total £320
1st £110 | Others £40 | Race Total £310
1st £110 | Others £40 | Race Total £310
1st £115 | Others £40 | Race Total £315
1st £120 | Others £40 | Race Total £320
1st £105 | Others £40 | Race Total £305
```

---

To get all the dog name you need iterate the parent element.

```
import requests
import json
headers = {'User-Agent':
       'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/355490?meeting=355490'
response =requests.get(url,headers=headers)
data=json.loads(response.text)
for d in data[0]['races']:
    for dog in d['traps']:
        print(dog['dogName'])
```

This will print all 60 names.

```
Talking Lulu
Demolition Dolly
Holycross Jo Jo
Fieldview Gramps
Fieldview Darcie
Blackrose Frog
Kilbreedy Gaga
Yorkstreet Milly
Blackrose Angus
Greencroft Snowy
Marcos Veggera
Ramors Flash
Dan The Tail
Killinan Fairy
Knockalton Bella
Howl At The Moon
Westmead Boss
Rockhill Romeo
Fieldview Gem
Only One Ding
Fieldview Jet
Leazes Samuel
Glassmoss Sally
Fieldview Franky
Talamh Dochais
Greencroft Spot
Greencroft Jed
Footfield Bee
Hather Pixie
Makeit My Dog
Makeit Mos Bro
Droopys Cristina
Puckane Panda
Hollywood Coco
Fieldview Dolly
Ballyphilip Bill
Bees Charm
Crossfield Hal
Savana Jody
Savana Hottie
Greencroft Briny
Savana Dan Dan
Savana Diamond
Savana Schnappes
Savana Pegasus
Millroad Captian
Savana Pimms
Ballyhoe Vouga
Fieldview Myles
Hollander
Savana Tequila
Ballygibba Chip
Rockburst Tess
All About Will
Clockwork Girl
Roma Lady
Fieldview Pancho
Harry Boy
Rahyvira Lady
Cobblers Girl
```

Comment: Great!!!Please accept the answer by clicking on hollow under down vote button.https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: thanks Kunduk, just one more thing, how do i print the dogName, as the process you explained kicks out an "KeyError: 'dogName'"

Comment: @Paul : Added the answer.